# GWT Maven plugin: Generating non-String parameters in the Messages class

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I have a property in my "Messages.properties" file that has an argument that uses number formatting:

```
my.message=File exceeds {0,number,0.0}MB.
```

When I run the `gwt:i18n` Maven goal, it generates a `Messages` interface based on the properties in my "Messages.properties" file (like normal):

```
public interface Messages extends com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages {
  //...

  @DefaultMessage("File exceeds {0,number,0.0}MB.")
  @Key("my.message")
  String my_message(String arg0);

  //...
}
```

The problem is that the method parameter is a `String`.  When I run the application, it gives me an error because the message argument expects a number, but a String is supplied (the error message is, "Only Number subclasses may be formatted as a number").

How do I configure Maven to have it change this parameter to number (like a `float` or `Number`)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the discussion above, I have decided to complement my previous answer.
First of all, as far as I know there's no way you can use the existing i18n Maven goal (and GWT's I18NCreator) to do what is asked.
Secondly, after researching a bit more on the Generator solution I had suggested, I found that:

- Michael is right that you wouldn't pick up errors at compile time using the interface method with look up for properties (a sin in GWT) as suggested above. However, this is still the simplest/quickest way to do it.
- You can ensure compile-time check by writing your own interface which
  is kept up-to-date with the properties file, having one method for each property, and then getting your
  generator to write a class which implements that interface. Notice
  that when you change a property on the properties file, you only need
  to change the interface you wrote. If you've written the Generator
  properly, it will never have to be changed again! The best way to go
  about method names is probably follow GWT: if a property is called
  the.prop.one, then the method name is the_prop_one(..).
- If you really don't want to maintain an interface manually, the only
  way I can see is for you to write your own version of    I18NCreator.
  This is because the maven goal i18n is not a GWT    compiler
  parameter, but a call for the maven plugin to write
  Messages/Constants interfaces based on properties files found in the 
  class path. Therefore, if you write your own I18NCreator, you will
  have to also write a Maven plugin that you can use to call it before 
  compiling the GWT application. Or, to make it simpler, you can simply
  run your I18NCreator manually (using the good-old java command to run
  it) every time you change your properties file keys (of course,
  there's no need to run it when only actual messages are changed).

Personally, I would just write and maintain my properties file and the interface that mirrors it manually. The Generator will always look at the properties file and generate the methods that correspond to the properties (with whatever arguments are required based on the actual message), so if the interface you wrote reflects the properties file, the class generated by the Generator will always implement it correctly.

Comment: Regarding point #2, if you are manually maintaining the interface, then there is no point in creating a Generator for it!  I think point #3 (creating your own version of i18nCreator) is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: The point of having the generator (point #2) is so that you have different implementations for different Locales linked automatically by GWT. Also, when you change a message in the properties file, all you need to do it compile and the Generator will update the implementation classes accordingly (but if you change the number of arguments in the message, you must also change the interface). About  the issue you opened: I think it's a good point and should be quite easy for them to change the way they parse the messages to allow numeric arguments. That would make Messages much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this feature is not supported by GWT I18NCreator (which is what the maven i18n goal calls). You would have to write your own Generator to do that.
I have written a couple of Generators and it's not as hard as you may think.
In your case, you would want to write a Generator that creates an instance of an interface similar to GWT's Messages (but you can use your own) but which has the added functionality that you want when decoding messages.
The following how-to little guide may help you, as it seems it's pretty much what I did as well and it works:

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/msg/ae249ea67c2c3435?pli=1

I found that the easiest way to write a GWT Generator is to actually write a test class with the code you would want generated in your IDE (and with the help of auto-completion, syntax-checks etc), and then past/adapt it to the writer calls like this:

```
writer.println("public void doSomething() { /* implement */ }");
```

And don't forget to tell your module (module.gwt.xml file) which interface needs to be generated, and with which class, like this:

```
<generate-with  class="mycompany.utils.generators.MyGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable class="mycompany.messages.MyCoolPropertiesReader" />
</generate-with>
```

In the Generator code, you can use Java with all its great features (not limited to GWT-translatable code) so it shouldn't be hard to implement what you want. In the client-side code, you can then just do:

```
public interface MyCoolPropertiesReader {
  public String getMessage(String propKey, Object... parameters);
}

public class MyClientSideClass {
  MyCoolPropertiesReader reader = GWT.create(MyCoolPropertiesReader.class);
  String msg = reader.getMessage("my.message", 10);
  // do more work
}
```

A test Generator that I wrote (a GWT "reflective" getter and setter, as it were) looks like this:

```
public class TestGenerator extends Generator {

@Override
public String generate(TreeLogger logger, GeneratorContext context,
  String typeName) throws UnableToCompleteException {
  try {
    TypeOracle oracle = context.getTypeOracle();
    JClassType requestedClass = oracle.getType(typeName);
    String packageName = requestedClass.getPackage().getName();
    String simpleClassName = requestedClass.getSimpleSourceName();
    String proxyClassName = simpleClassName + "GetterAndSetter";
    String qualifiedProxyClassName = packageName + "." + proxyClassName;
    System.out.println("Created a class called: " + qualifiedProxyClassName);

    PrintWriter printWriter = context.tryCreate(logger, packageName, className);
    if (printWriter == null) return null;
      ClassSourceFileComposerFactory composerFactory = new ClassSourceFileComposerFactory(packageName, className);
      composerFactory.addImport("test.project.shared.GetterAndSetter");
      composerFactory.addImplementedInterface("GetterAndSetter<" + underlyingTypeName + ">");
      SourceWriter writer = composerFactory.createSourceWriter(context, printWriter);
      if (writer != null) {
        JField[] fields = requestedClass.getFields();
        for (JField field : fields) {
          createSetterMethodForField(typeName, writer, field);
        }
        writer.indent();
        writer.println("public void set(" + typeName + " target, String path, Object value) {");
        writer.indent();
        createIfBlockForFields(writer, fields, true);
        writer.outdent();
        writer.println("}");
        writer.println();
        writer.println("public <K> K get(" + typeName + " target, String path) {");
        writer.indent();
        createIfBlockForFields(writer, fields, false);
        writer.outdent();
        writer.println("}");
        writer.println();
        writer.outdent();
        writer.commit(logger);
      }
      return packageName + "." + proxyClassName;
    } catch(NotFoundException nfe) {
      throw new UnableToCompleteException();
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not what I'm looking for.  I want to use the existing i18nCreator utility.

Comment: No, using a Generator like this won't work I don't think.  With this solution, my source code would have to contain hard-coded Strings for the property names.  The benefit to having the Messages class that i18nCreator generates is that it creates a separate method for each property in your .properties file, so the property names are statically checked by the compiler (if you enter an incorrect property name in a String, the compiler won't catch it).

Comment: Also, I think GWT does some special things behind the scenes with the Messages class in order to determine the locale of the user and use the correct .properties file.  I don't know how I would reproduce this functionality.

Comment: By the way: I created a ticket in the GWT issue tracker about this issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6924

Comment: When the generator writes a class, you can generate a method for each property... this is exactly what GWT does with Messages and Constants! You are right that the way I suggested, you wouldn't have a method for each property, but you can just as easily write it the way you want.

Comment: Also, to "know" the locales, you have to learn how to use this: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/rebind/LocaleUtils.html     This makes locale information available to GWT Generators. Your generator can then generate a different class for each available Locale, and GWT will "know" which one to download just like it knows which "Messages" implementation to download to the client when loading the application.

Comment: The GWT's DynamicMessageGenerator's code will probably help you a lot if you dare implement the Generator yourself: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dmesg/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/gwt/dmesg/rebind/DynamicMessagesGenerator.java?r=21

Comment: But in order for this Generator technique to work, I must already have an interface that defines all the methods in the class (this interface cannot be generated at run-time).  Otherwise, what am I going to pass into `GWT.create()`?  The i18nCreator tool generates this interface for me (as part of the build process when compiling my project).  For example, the `Messages` interface in this code sample is from a .java source file that is generated by i18nCreator: `Messages myMessages = GWT.create(Messages.class); myMessages.my_first_property(); myMessages.my_second_property();`

Comment: I also thought that before, but after doing some tests, I found that not to be the case. You may refer to the class you generated in your code, but only after running the Generator for the first time, of course! What I did was, I created an empty interface just to use as a parameter to GWT.create()... I generated a class which implements the empty interface, say EmptyInterface and wrote "EmptyInterface ei = GWT.create(Person.class). Note that Person.class just tells GWT what generator to use! It's just a kind of marker that tells GWT to look at my module file and see which Generator to use.

Comment: It will return whatever class my Generator wants to return!!! After doing this, let's say I generated a class called NotImplementingAnything... I can then write in my client-side code: NotImplmentingAnything nia = GWT.create(Person.class); If you're using an IDE, you must add the folder ".generated" to your build path sources in order to see this class. It may be a bit of a strange way to go, but this just works! You should try this. It took me just a few minutes to test it.

Comment: Just to correct one thing: if you then clean your project and try to build, unfortunately your build will fail... it's better if you generate your class the way I described, then get your IDE to extract an interface for it which you can then make your Generator implement, so you don't have this problem. It's good practice anyway .. but you'll have to add/change methods to your interface when you change a property key... but the same would be true if you were using Messages, because changing keys in the property file will cause Messages to change method names, breaking code that was using them.

Comment: OMG, I'm tired, it's Friday evening!! I meant the Generator has to write a class that implements the interface you extracted from the previously generated class (you could write the interface from scratch if you like), not implement the interface, obviously.

Comment: So you're saying: I can use the Generator to actually generate the .java source file which contains my `Messages` interface?  So, in the Generator class, instead of doing `PrintWriter pw = context.tryCreate(...);` I would do `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("Messages.java");`  Then, once I've created my interface, I can remove the `NotImplmentingAnything nia = GWT.create(Person.class)` line from my code and replace it with code that uses the interface that I just generated `Messages messages = GWT.create(Messages.class)`.